# Implementing of a custom load function in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, ebcdic

I am trying to read an ebcdic IBM file by using PIG (hadoop), so I need to create my custom load function.

The dafault getInputFormat() is as follows:

```
@Override
    public InputFormat getInputFormat() {
        return new TextInputFormat();
    }
```

I think I need to write my own InputFormat to read ebcdic file, am I right?
If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: you can look into
 http://www.syncsort.com/en/Solutions/Hadoop-Solutions/Mainframe-Offload-to-Hadoop

Comment: Actually, I am looking for a free solution. Anyway, thanks for The link